# CouchbaseClient VS CouchbaseCluster

Tags: java, couchbase

I am trying to implement couchbase in my application.

I am confused with

**`com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient`**

AND

**`com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster`**.

I tried to google on CouchbaseClient vs CouchbaseCluster but didn't found which one is better & Pros and Cons.

I know we have 3 types of Couchbase Client, one is vBucket-aware, one is traditional old client which support auto clustering via Moxi-Server.

Can someone who have already used couchbase provides me some link or detailed information about these two Java-Client.

I have done some homework on CouchbaseClient and CouchbaseCluster like inserting, updating, deleting documents via both. 
In CouchbaseClient the documents stored are Serialized and you cannot view and edit those documents via Couchbase Admin Console, whereas if Documents like StringDocument, JsonDocument, JsonArrayDocument stored via Couchbase cluster can be viewed and are editable over Couchbase Admin Console.

My requirements is I want to use a couchbase client which is AutoConfiurable (vBucket-aware) like if I add new nodes to a cluster, it will auto detect it, or if any node failed, it will auto detect it and does not throw any exception. Further, if I add new cluster, I'd like it to auto detect it and start using it. I don't want to modify the application code for all these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now two generations of official Couchbase Java SDKs:

- generation 1 (currently `1.4.x`, not sure of the patch version) is derived from an old Memcached client, `Spymemcached`... it is now bugfixes only, and it's the one where you have `CouchbaseClient` as the primary API.
- generation 2 is a rewrite, layered into a `core` artifact and `java-client` artifact in Maven. Current version is `2.1.3`. This is the one where you deal with `CouchbaseCluster`.

In the old one, you'd have to instantiate one `CouchbaseClient` for each bucket you deal with.

In the new generation, the notions of cluster and bucket are first class citizens and you can (and should) reuse the same `Cluster` instance to open references to different `Bucket`s. The `Bucket`s should also be reused (don't open the same bucket several times). Resources are better mutualized this way.

Also, the new generation has more coherent APIs, uses `RxJava` for asynchronous processing, etc... It is cluster-aware and will get updates of the topology of the cluster (new nodes, failing nodes, etc...).

Note that these two generations are differents artifacts in Maven (old one is `couchbase-client` while new one is `java-client`).

There's no way you can get such a notification if you "add new cluster", but that operation doesn't really make sense to me...

Comment: Thanks Simon, Yes I read about these two different version or generations of Couchbase Java's SDK.
Yes both of them have their own advantages. So suppose in case you want to save a simple POJO to couchbase,  you should go with Couchbase client as it directly store your object in serialized form and will give you in desearialized form where as in CouchbaseCluster you have to map your POJO to Documents and then store it and vice-versa. But as you said the new generation cluster and bucket are first class citizens and it gives you more control and power over dealing with cluster's and bucket.